# Get the most recent transaction via the SDK

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I'm trying to get the most recent transaction (across all transaction types) via the Quickbooks SDK.  I am using QB XML via the `<TransactionQueryRq/>` type.  I can certainly get a listing of transactions but how I can say "Give me the most recent."?  I don't see any sort of ordering component to this query type.

In SQL I would say something like (or using `LIMIT` etc):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Transactions ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC
```

I'm using the SDK and C# if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question but I can't claim it. :)

See: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/809474-get-the-most-recent-transaction-of-any-type

Basically, this cannot be done.  The solution I used was the following algo:

```
date = today()
results = []
while(results == []) {
  results = run TransactionQueryRq with TxnDate==date
  date = date - 1day
}

latest transaction = get transaction with max TxnDate from results
```

The amount of daily transactions for me is not high, so I don't need to use an iterator.  But if one has many daily transactions, an interator may be needed.